# Market Equilibrium

Tags: microeconomics, self-study

Can help me with part b of this problem?

The demand for wine is given by the equation $QD = 500 – 20P$, where $P$ is the price of wine per litre and $QD$ is the quantity of wine demanded in litres. The supply of wine is given by the equation $QS = 30P$.

**a) Solve for the equilibrium quantity and price of wine.**

The current equilibrium would be $500 - 20P = 30P$.  therefore the equilibrium price is $P=$ $100 and equilibrium quantity is 1500.

**b) Suppose that a $1 per litre tax is levied on the wine producers. Calculate the new equilibrium quantity and price of wine after tax.**

Is the new supply $QS = 30P + 1$? 
So the new equilibrium can be obtain from $30P+1 = 500-20P$.  But I get decimal places?  Or is the equilibrium $30P + 1Q$?

Comment: I edited some Latex form, but you should check your maths for the a).

Answer (score 3):

For (a) it appears that you made a slight miscalculation; the equilibrium price cannot be $100 since in that case **Quantity Demanded** = -1500.

For (a) the equilibrium price is $10 and Quantity of 300.

The trick to getting (b) is seeing the viewpoint of the producers and the buyers rather than just applying the maths.

Producers: 30P where P is the price per litre that they **actually** receive.
 
Buyers:  500 - 20P where P is the amount that they **actually** pay.

Since producers now pay an extra $1 per litre in tax, their **actual** price is one dollar less therefore 
Producers with tax is now **30(P-1)**.

If you work out the equlibrium using the same method as in (a), you will get a price equilibrium of $10.6 with a quantity of 288.